# How to add class to the last image of the last post in a loop

Tags: loop

ok, I'm creating a portfolio page, I want add a class to my last portfolio thumbnail. currently I have a class added to the div of the last portfolio item. I want to add it to the thumbnail, not the div itself.

my code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="testing_imran<?php echo $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' imd_last' : '' ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'main-image portfolio' ) ); ?>
</div>           
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want that "imd_last" class added to the post-thumbnail not the div. how can I do it? by the way, the thumbnails have a class attached as you can see, I just want to add an extra class to the last thumbnail.
[image]

Comment: Pass the class as needed to the `the_post_thumbnail()` call?.. Your snippet essentially already has everything you are asking to do.

Comment: currently the class is adding to the div, I want to add it to the image.

Comment: added a screenshot fro better understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use CSS pseudo attributes for that.
You can simply use `:first-child` and `:last-child` to target first and last element for CSS styling.

Here is how you do that with CSS pseudo attributes.

```
div.post:last-child div.testing_imran img {
    your styles for last image
}
```

Also FYI, your code will work too, if you want to target last image in CSS file. You don't really need to add CSS class to image itself, but adding CSS class to div container will work fine too.

```
div.testing_imran.imd_last img {
    your styles for last image
}
```

If you want to targe image in jQuery, then same rules work for jQuery too.